# Operator in Hilbert space of a spin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I'm studying quantum mechanics with Shankar's "Principles of Quantum Mechanics" 2nd edition. I'm afraid that it might be a boring question but I can't understand the following statement (389p):

We assumed once again that there is a magnetic moment operator $\mathbb{\mu}$ associated with the spin angular momentum. Since any operator on $\mathbb{V_s}$ is a linear combination of the identity and the spin operators, and since $\mathbb{\mu}$ is a vector operator, we conclude that
$$ \mathbb{\mu} = \gamma S $$

I can't really understand what those lines means. Why is any operator on $\mathbb{V_s}$ a linear combination of the identity and the spin operators? It seems that my understanding on the spin Hilbert space is not concrete.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your textbook, but I might have understood the point. Considering a $\frac{1}{2}$-spin particle (for example)  you should know that a suitable Hilbert space to represent the system is $\mathbb{C}^2$. Moreover Pauli matrices $\sigma_i $ for $i = x,y,z$ toghether with the identity matrix form a base for the vector space of linear operators $\mathbb{C}^2 \to \mathbb{C}^2$ (4 independent matrices in a 4-dimensional vector space). So the conclusion follows for your moment operator $\mu$.